# Azure - WAF & Subpage access/view restrictions

Tags: azure, subdomain, azureportal

Is it possible in the Azure Web App Firewall if I have a simple web app (with let's say only an index.html, which has links to private.html and public.html) to restrict the access only on 1 subpage (private.html) or to configure that here on that subpage you have to authenticate?

Additionally, is there any possibility to set up that you have to authenticate with Azure AD on the WAF before going through it to a Web app?

Answer (score 0):

for the second question, you can use Easy Auth: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization

for the first one, unless you code some backend logic to block users there's no way.
As another option, you can setup Azure API Management in front of the web app (consumption plan) and validade headers to avoid access on private.html